# my heat pumps power will tripping

Tags: hvac

My heat pump when I start condenser fan wil run if go to command in compressor suddenly my elcb will tripping. My a/c technician told me compressor is grounded , i changed that compressor 7months before , what is the reason for compressor grounded suddenly

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with your English, particularly the first sentence. Could you have someone fix it up for you?

Answer (score 1):

If the system oil becomes Acidic the varnish will be eaten off the motor windings causing the motor to short to ground. This can happen in just a few days for a system that was not clean or completely evacuated. There are quick acid test kits that will show if there is acid in the system in a few seconds. If the system shows acid I recomend a flush not a neutralizer because neutralizers leave residue. A product like quick shot acid flush moves the contamination to the filter dryer. I have had several systems that this worked very well on. It won't help your current compressor but may keep this from happening again. If you have the system repaired insist on having the system pumped down to 500 microns or lower to get the moisture out. I usually try for 100 on a system that has had problems and hold it there to get the system dry.